# Python error in array manipulation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 arrays (for the sake of the example, let's name them A and B) and i perform the following manipulations at them, but i get an error at the assignment of "d2" in my code.

```
n = len(tracks) #tracks is a list containing different-length 3d arrays 
n=30; #test with a few tracks 
length = len(tracks) #list containing the total number of "samples"
perm_index = np.random.permutation(length) #uniform sampling without replacement
subset_len = 5 # choose the size of subset of tracks A
subset_A = [tracks[x:x+1] for x in xrange(0, subset_len, 1)]
subset_B = [tracks[x:x+1] for x in xrange(subset_len, n, 1)]
tempA = distance_calc.dist_calcsub(len(subset_A), subset_A)  # distance matrix calculation
tempA = mcp.sym_mcp(len(subset_A), tempA)    # symmetrize mcp ???
tempB = distance_calc.dist_calcsubs(subset_A, subset_B)  # distance matrix calculation
#symmetrize mcp ? ? its not diagonal, symmetric . . .

A = affinity.aff_conv(60, tempA) # conversion to affinity 
B = affinity.aff_conv(60, tempB) # conversion to affinity 

#((row,col)) = np.shape(A)
#A = normalization_affinity.norm_aff(row, col, A) # normalization of affinity matrix

# Normalize A and B for Laplacian using row sums of W, where W = [A B; B' B'*A^-1*B].
# Let d1 = [A B]*1, d2 = [B' B'*A^-1*B]*1, dhat = sqrt(1./[d1; d2]).
d1 = np.sum( np.vstack((A, np.transpose(B))) )
d2 = np.sum(B,0) + np.dot(np.sum(np.transpose(B),0), np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(A), B ))
dhat = np.transpose(np.sqrt( 1/ np.hstack((d1, d2)) ))
A = A* np.dot( dhat[0:subset_len], np.transpose(dhat[0:subset_len]) )
B = B* np.dot( dhat[0:subset_len], np.transpose(dhat[subset_len:n]) )
```

The error again is "ValueError: matrices are not aligned." because the np.dot vectors are 1d vectors of different size; I know the reason why this is happening but I am following exactly the equations to perform the Nystrom method.

P.S: I am following the method described in p.90-92 in this thesis: [thesis link](http://people.csail.mit.edu/lauren/publications/LaurenODonnellThesis.pdf)

Comment: What shape did you expect `np.sum(B, 0)` to have? You're summing each row into a single value, so you get 10 values. Did you want a 10x4 matrix with each row replaced by 4 copies of the row's sum or something?

Comment: i am expecting to get the row sums of B in any case; The A and B are only for illustration purposes. In this case, i am getting exactly what i am expecting to get.

Comment: You really need to summarize the relevant information from that linked thesis so that the question makes sense on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the paper, you've got *two* problems here.

Let's start with the information you left out of your question. You're trying to do this operation:

```
bc + B.T * A^−1 * br
```

> where `ar` and `br` are column vectors containing the row sums of `A` and `B` and `bc` is
>   the column sum of `B`.

In particular, you're mapping that `A^-1 * br` to `np.dot( np.linalg.pinv(A), np.sum(B, 0))`.

---

The first problem is that `np.linalg.pinv` is the pseudo-inverse, A+, not the multiplicative inverse, A^-1. Using a completely different operation just because it doesn't give you an error doesn't solve the problem.

So, how *do* you calculate the multiplicative inverse? Well, you can't. In general, the multiplicative inverse doesn't *exist* for non-square matrices, so given a 5x10 `A`, you're stuck right at the beginning.

---

Anyway, the second problem comes from the fact that your `br` isn't a column vector. If you want to think in matrix terms, as the paper does, it's a row vector, 10x1 instead of 1x10. If you want to think in numpy ndarray terms, it's a 1D `(10,)` array instead of a 2D `(1, 10)` array. If you think of the operation in matrix multiplication terms, you can't multiply a 10x5 matrix with a 10x1 matrix; if you think of it in NumPy terms as the multidimensional dot product, you can't multiply a `(10, 5)` array with a `(10,)` array.

It's true that you can extend the dot product to specifically the domain of MxN matrices vs. M vectors, and under that definition your multiplication would make sense. But that's not the definition used by either the paper's standard matrix multiplication notation or NumPy's `dot` function. So, what can you do? Well, note that the operation you're trying to do is commutative, so swapping the order of operands is perfectly legal—and if you do that, then it *does* happen to correspond to the general dot product. So, you could write this as `np.dot(np.sum(B, 0), np.linalg.pinv(A))` and get the result you want. And there are a number of other ways you could transform the arrays that are idempotent in your matrix-vs.-vector multiplication domain but meaningful for `np.dot`, and they will all get you the same result. For example, `np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(A).T, np.sum(B, 0))` will also work.

I'm also not sure why you're using dot product in the first place. I don't see anything in the notation to imply that

But all of this is a sideshow; if you inverted `A` properly, you would have something with the same dimensions as `A`, and multiply a 5x10 matrix with a 10x1 vector, or a `(5, 10)` array with a `(10,)` array, is already perfectly well defined. The only problem is that, again, you can't generally invert non-square matrices, so there's no way you can actually get to this place.

---

So, the real solution is to go back to wherever you decided on those shapes for `A` and `B` and try again.

In particular, it's pretty clear from the illustration in the paper showing the derivation of `A` and `B` from the larger matrix that the height of `A` is the height of `B`, and the width of `A` is the width of `B.T`, which is of course the height of `B` again.

Also, if the larger matrix is supposed to symmetric, and `A` is the upper left corner of a symmetric matrix, `A` has to be symmetric.

I also think you've mixed up row-column order and x-y order a few times, and `bc` is supposed to the column sums of `B`, not the column sums of `B.T` (which would just be the row sums of `B`, flipped into a row vector instead of a column vector).

While we're at it, let's use methods and operators where possible instead of writing everything in the longest possible way.

So, I think what you wanted is something like this:

```
A = np.random.random_sample((4, 4)) # square
A = (A + A.T) / 2 # and symmetric
B = np.random.random_sample((4, 10))
ar = A.sum(1)
br = B.sum(1)
bc = B.sum(0) # not B.T.sum(0), that's just br again!
d1 = ar + br
d2 = bc + np.dot(B.T, np.dot(np.linalg.inv(A), br))
```

Without actually reading the paper I can't be sure this is what you actually want, but this looks like it fits with a quick skim of those two pages, and it runs without any errors, so hopefully you can at least look at the results and see if they are what you want.

Comment: the thing is that the equations do not mention that i should transpose the inv(A) but i should use it like this. I mean, i could do some tricks to get the job done but in theory it is not like this. :s

Comment: @GeorgeLaza: I don't know what equations you're looking at or what form they're in, since you haven't shown them. Maybe they're expecting you to have a row vector rather than a column vector. Or maybe, as I explained in the answer, they're relying on the fact that the dot product of a matrix and a vector is unambiguous (unlike the general N-dimensional case).

Comment: i'm trying to do the Nystrom approximation as explained in the corresponding chapter of this thesis[1]. I would be glad if you could help me on this.


  [1]:http://people.csail.mit.edu/lauren/publications/LaurenODonnellThesis.pdf

Comment: @GeorgeLaza: First, if that's relevant to the question, edit the question to include it, don't bury it in a comment. Second, do you not understand my explanation of why it probably doesn't matter, or do you just not agree with it? At any rate, I'm not going to read a 200-page thesis to try to figure out where it explains what you're trying to do so I can try to guess what you may be missing in your attempt to translate it in some way you haven't explained.

Comment: i read your answer but i think i am making a logical error and not a syntax one, that's why i wanted another pair of eyes to see the logic behind it. The Nystrom method is only 2 pages long that's why i post the link of the thesis (p.90-92). Of course i don't expect you to read the whole thing :)

Comment: @GeorgeLaza: From a quick glance, it looks like they're using `br` as a `(1,10)` matrix, while you've calculated it as a `(10,)` matrix. Just as I said. Let me edit the answer for more detail.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your time and consideration. I am currently reviewing both your answer and some major changes in my code. When i'm done, i'll get back right to you.

Comment: Is it possible to move our conversation to chat? I don't have the rep to do it. :(

Comment: @GeorgeLaza: If you don't have the rep for chat, me inviting you there won't work. I try to invite you, you see nothing, I sit around waiting forever. (Or they may have fixed it so I get an error message, but that's not much more useful.)

Comment: I see. Here is my email: gelazari@yahoo.com and my Skype name:gelazari. Feel free to add me if you want so as to have a robust conversation. Sorry to bother you, but you seem to have a tremendous insight and understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are summing over the first dimension of B, so the shape is 10, the size of the second dimension of B.

You can calculate

```
np.dot( np.sum(B, 0), np.linalg.pinv(A))
```

but this gives you a vector with 5 elements, but B_T has only a size of 4. So something doesn't fit in your sample data.